# Mock Confusion with Path

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a test below using `mock` on Python 2.6.

```
@patch('testme.check.RE.query')
def test_check(query):
  query.filter.one = MagicMock(return_value=None)
  ....
  assert against_experiment(cl, ei, cd)
```

Inside the module I want to test, I have

```
def check_against_experiment(c, e, c):
  re = RE.query.filter(RE.e_id == e).one()
```

Two questions:

When inspecting `re = RE.query.filter(RE.e_id == e).one()`, I see `<MagicMock name='query.filter().one()' id='62856528'>`.

Why isn't this returning `None`?

Another question is when I change `@path('testme.check.RE.query')` to `@path('testme.check.RE.query')` and change `query.filter.one` to `query.one`, I notice that nothing is mocked out. Why is this the case?

Comment: When you inspected, did you check to see what is inside `return_value`? Also, just as a test, put `return_value=123` and check `return_value` as well. As for your second question, it is all based on your relative imports. I don't know how your project is set up and how things are referenced to one another, but it is probably due to that. Also, these are the same: `@path('testme.check.RE.query')` to `@path('testme.check.RE.query')`

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling `RE.query.filter(RE.e_id == e)` in your function-under-test, it is returning a new **unconfigured** `MagicMock`, and then you are calling its `one` function, which is generating that default `return_value`.

You probably want to set the `return_value` of `filter` to be a new `Mock` whose `one` function returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is what you want to do is

```
query.filter.return_value.one.return_value = None
```

Default mock's `return_value` attribute is a `MagickMock` object (AFAIK allocated as lazy property).

IMHO try to avoid this kind of mock configurations, take your class/function more clear and narrow to avoid object browsing. These kind of test make source and tests tangled and create a solid fence to do refactoring.

For your second question I can just point you to [Where to Patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) *must read* document. From what you say is impossible to find the root cause by I can bet the answer is always in this documentation's chapter.